# Query to insert records from one table into another table based on the column of the first table

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014, pivot

I have a table with the structure below :

```
Table(customer_Num  int , Channel_Id  Varchar(50) ,  Branch_Code  int)
```

and some example data for this table is :

```
                  Table
__________________________________________
customer_Num  |  Channel_Id  |  Branch_Code 
    1         |    'I'       |     1000
    1         |    'Y'       |     1001
    1         |    'L'       |     1002
```

and the final result I want in the output is :

```
                          Result_table
__________________________________________________________
customer_Num  | I_branch_Code |  Y_branch_Code  | L_Branch_Code
    1               1000             1001             1002
```

is there a better solution rather than using continuous `Insert`  queries? Cause with this query 
I will have many nulls in my final table!And I also won't have the result in one record.

```
 insert into Result_table (customer_Num  ,I_branch_Code )
 select customer_Num   , Branch_Code 
 from Table
 where Channel_Id   = 'I';

 insert into Result_table (customer_Num  ,Y_branch_Code  )
 select customer_Num   , Branch_Code 
 from Table
 where Channel_Id   = 'Y';


insert into Result_table (customer_Num  ,L_Branch_Code)
select customer_Num   , Branch_Code 
from Table
where Channel_Id  = 'L';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15) clause. You can see a working example in this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c5a20d3368848a404aa56be4cf17a5ca).

The query is:

```
SELECT customer_num
  ,p.I AS I_Branch_Code
  ,p.Y AS Y_Branch_Code
  ,p.L AS L_Branch_Code
FROM
(
  SELECT customer_num
    ,Channel_Id
    ,Branch_code
  FROM [table]
)s
PIVOT
(
  MAX(Branch_Code) FOR Channel_Id IN ([I], [Y], [L])
) p
```